# Merge two numpy array's of different shape into a single array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy array's **a** and **b** of length 53 and 82 respectively. I would like to merge them into a single array because I want to use the 53+82=135 length array say call it **c** for plotting.

I tried

```
c = a+b
```

but I am getting **ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape**

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [numpy.concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) instead of array addition

```
c = numpy.concatenate((a, b))
```

**Implementation**

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(53)
b = np.arange(82)
c = np.concatenate((a, b))
```

**Output**

```
c.shape
(135, )
```

Comment: what if a and b have different shape? (ex: a.shape=(12,8), b.shape=(12,))

Answer (score 4):

Use [`numpy.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
In [5]: import numpy as np

In [6]: a = np.arange(5)                                                                         

In [7]: b = np.arange(11)                                                                        

In [8]: np.concatenate((a, b))                                                                   
Out[8]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

For 1-D arrays you can also use [`numpy.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
In [9]: np.hstack((a, b))                                                                       
Out[9]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]
```

Comment: I get the error that "only integer scalars can be converted to scalar index"

Comment: @DineshVG Share your input data?

Comment: Something similar to this -
`0.00764538,  0.00871098,  0.00959187,  0.01028805,  0.00884634` for one array and `0.17873864,  0.1273831 ,  0.07530486,  0.08724997,  0.07698863,
        0.04452086,  0.04699075,  0.06169301,  0.08862764,  0.12403291,
        0.26097335,  0.49944897,  0.4297591 ,  0.37918886` for the second array...