# NumPy: concat/stack ndarrays of different size

Tags: python, numpy

I have multiple different sized ndarrays (e.g. `a = np.arange(3)`, `b = np.arange(4)` which I'd like to concat/stack to one ndarray `res` with the dtype `ndarray`:

```
> res
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3])], dtype=np.ndarray)
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: That's not concatenating.  That's an object array containing arrays, a bastardized list.

Comment: Why do you want to combine these arrays into one?  What advantage would it have over a list?

Answer (score 0):

Considering answer [Merge two numpy array's of different shape into a single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336803/merge-two-numpy-arrays-of-different-shape-into-a-single-array) you can use function *concatenate* from *numpy* module:

```
a = np.arange(3)
b = np.arange(4)
c = np.concatenate((a, b))
```

Comment: this results to `array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3])`, not `array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3])], dtype=np.ndarray)`

Comment: Probably like that `c = np.array([a,b], dtype=object)` ?